# Cassandra fails to run - using Intellij on windows

Tags: java, apache, intellij-idea, cassandra-2.0

Well I followed the https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/RunningCassandraInIDEA
to setup the cassandra project locally.

but when I run, i'm getting the below mentioned error log

```
Failed to auto configure default logger context
Reported exception:
ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.JoranException: Could not open URL [file://E:/ProjectsV2/Cassandra/conf/logback.xml].
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:77)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:152)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.<clinit>(CassandraDaemon.java:96)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: E
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:957)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:917)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1012)
    at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:48)
    ... 13 more
17:53:47,964 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [file://E:/ProjectsV2/Cassandra/conf/logback.xml] at [file://E:/ProjectsV2/Cassandra/conf/logback.xml]
17:53:52,546 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@1055e4af - Could not open URL [file://E:/ProjectsV2/Cassandra/conf/logback.xml]. java.net.UnknownHostException: E
    at java.net.UnknownHostException: E
    at  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at  at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:957)
    at  at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:917)
    at  at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1012)
    at  at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:998)
    at  at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
    at  at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:48)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:77)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:152)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:129)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:302)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:288)
    at  at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.<clinit>(CassandraDaemon.java:96)
    at  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:116)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:116)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:448)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:576)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Expecting URI in variable: [cassandra.config].  Please prefix the file with file:\\\ for local files or file:\\<server>\ for remote files. Aborting. If you are executing this from an external tool, it needs to set Config.setClientMode(true) to avoid loading configuration.
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.getStorageConfigURL(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.YamlConfigurationLoader.loadConfig(YamlConfigurationLoader.java:85)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.loadConfig(DatabaseDescriptor.java:127)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.<clinit>(DatabaseDescriptor.java:111)
    ... 7 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any help and guidance in this would be great. Thanks a lot.

PS: i'm a complete noob with this, so a brief explanation will go a long way in improving me. Thanks again

Comment: you tried to connect to file://E:/ProjectsV2/Cassandra/conf/logback.xml , but it fails,,, are you sure it is their? It doesn't understand E as host... Try, for test, to unquote the rule that loads the file from Cassandra/conf

Comment: well i'm trying to run locally, i followed the mentioned steps from creating ant build and the rest. there was no mention of changing, for if you see in the mid of the log, it says the resource was found at the expected place, but could not be opened. if it had to be a url, how should i go about it then?

Comment: Try replacing file:// with file:///

Comment: That good to hear... Have 'fun' with it :-)

Comment: it is somewhat odd, unfair... to accept an answer from somebody else, when that one posts it later than the answer was giving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As copied from my comment:

replace

```
file://
```

with

```
file:///
```

Comment: The problem, when looking at my answer, is that it is unapparent when the comment (with answer) was made

Comment: Very nice answer, I upvoted it and subsequently I have removed mine.